# Proper way of setting up my input and output data for training CNN

Tags: python, normalization, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on the structuring my input and output for a CNN in which the input is different sized images, and for the different sized images are different sized vectors.

Example:

```
Name: mfaa-b-an165
Output: (278, 13)
Input: (276, 846, 3)
--> 
Name: mdms2-b-an405
Output: (538, 13)
Input: (276, 1491, 3)
-->
```

Here are some shapes of how the data is currently stored. I have to create 13 different CNN for each different feature, in which each CNN extract a separate feature from the feature vector.  The problem is though there isn't that much consistency in the number of output compared to input. 
The only constant is the number of rows, and color dimension, and the number of columns somehow has to be linked number of features extracted from that image.

My idea was to resize the x-axis of the image, such that would fit with the number of features extracted, but sometimes is this not possible..

Eg.

```
First example (mfaa-b-an165): 
278*3 = 834 => meaning removing 12 columns can provide me 3 output for the pooling layer. 

second exmaple (mdms2-b-an405):
538*3 = 1614 => Image should be larger => data should be added not possible.
```

This clearly doesn't seem to work.. Is there some other way i can make this work?..